# Why does ios11 clear the canvas tag in the web invisible region?

Tags: canvas, rendering, ios11

my iPhone from upgrading ios10 to ios11, and using the ios11 system to load a web page, there are two canvas tag on the web page. The web size may be  2 screen height. After loading HTML, web roll to the bottom, the following canvas is not shown, click on some pages in central sleect box, bottom canvas tag can be displayed, and then roll up the top of the canvas disappeared again, and then click on the page sleect in central box, the top of the canvas can be displayed, and then roll to the bottom, the bottom canvas disappeared again. but Ios10 can normally show two canvas tag. What happened in ios11.

Answer (score 0):

we resolved the problem, just use highChart repleace Canvas.